# How to test which component is consuming more battery in Ionic Mobile App

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I have an application in Ionic and i need to do benchmark testing of all the components and find which component is consuming more power

Answer (score 0):

Buy two phones. Then render each component alone on each phone, and see which one runs out of power first.